# How do I comment a Obj C typedef block with doxygen

Tags: objective-c, comments, doxygen, typedef

When I run doxygen on this Obj-C code, neither the signature nor the comment appears in the HTML output.  Do I need to add a tag (@typedef) or pass in settings such as ENABLE_PREPROCESSING, MACRO_EXPANSION, EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF, PREDEFINED, and
SHOW_FILES?  I've tried several combinations with no luck.

```
/**
 * This is the brief comment.  This is the detailed comment.
 *
 * @param error The error describing failure.
 */
typedef void(^ServiceCompletion)(NSError *error);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [Appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) has no problem with that  ;).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the @related tag (also know as \related, @relates and \relates).  Nothing else.  Very simple and elegant.  This tag tells Doxygen that the typedef it tags ***is related to*** the MyService interface.  This tag is required because the typedef is not a member of the interface.

Dimitri himself supplied the solution: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720046

```
/**
 * @related MyService
 *
 * This is the brief comment.  This is the detailed comment.
 *
 * @param error The error describing failure.
 */
typedef void(^ServiceCompletion)(NSError *error);

@interface MyService : NSObject
...
@end
```